# CSS clip-path fails on load in Safari

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, transition, clip-path

I've been playing with CSS `clip-path` property and made this pen animating a logo: http://codepen.io/alexcoady/pen/PqJavW. The code draws a number of divs and applies `clip-path`s to them dynamically based on some triangles I've generated.

This works as expected in Chrome (43.0.2357.124 (64-bit) ).

In Safari (8.0.4 + iOS), however, nothing shows up at all. Once I've opened the inspector I can uncheck the `clip-path` property, then I re-check it - the path is visible as expected.

Any ideas what I can do to ensure that Safari renders these paths first time round?

Thanks.

Comment: same issue here except for the first div is visible and rest are not. In my case even though i uncheck the clip path property from inspector and enable it again, the container does not show up.

When i remove clip path from 1st div and then apply it to 2nd div it gets rendered correctly with clipping. Extremely weird but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe only Chrome supports animated clip-paths.

I've also searched for a solution for this problem but the closest I can make out, is currently only Chrome can animate the points of an `SVGElement`.

Here are a few places to look for a solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#PolygonElement